# Grails 3: Can't push to heroku

Tags: git, grails, heroku

I was pushing the current git repository into the heroku. That online application was developed using Grails 3 and IntelliJ. And I don't know how to fix this error.

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 400 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 0), reused 5 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/gradle.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to desolate-springs-99606.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/desolate-springs-99606.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/desolate-springs-99606.git'
```

Answer (score 1):

The errors says that your app is not compatible with Gradle buildpack. I am not familiar with Grails framework and how can you deploy it to Heroku, so I can't give you specific answer. But you should follow instructions for  [Gradle buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-gradle). Buildpack is checking for three files `gradlew`, `build.gradle` or `settings.gradle`. If you already have those files in your app's directory, make sure they are committed.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku only detect automatically Grails 2.0 apps.

To deploy a Grails 3.0 you need to follow [Deploying Gradle Apps#Grails-3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-gradle-apps-on-heroku#using-grails-3)

Basically you need to add some tasks into your gradle.build and create a *Procfile*